# What is the scene depicted in the second "Waterdeep Digital Background" art?

Tags: lore, forgotten-realms, waterdeep-dragon-heist, art

In the [Free Remote D&D Resources archive](https://dnd.wizards.com/remote/archive) that Wizards of the Coast is providing, for April 30, 2020 there is a "Waterdeep Digital Backgrounds" zip file that includes artwork that one might be able to use as a background while videoconferencing. The second file (named "DnD_Video_bg-WDDH2") looks to be a scene outside of Waterdeep proper, with people along a path, a building (maybe some kind of temple), and the wall of Waterdeep in the background. I'm presuming putting a smaller version here counts as fair use:

> [image: Waterdeep scene 2]

**What is that building, and more generally where is this scene set?** Is it part of the *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist* book or storyline? (I don't remember seeing it in there, though probably I just missed it, but the filename saying "WDDH" makes me think it's related.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This image is from *Volo's Waterdeep Enchiridion* (a chapter in *Waterdeep: Dragon Heist*, also available separately on DM's Guild), and represents the **City of the Dead**, a ward within Waterdeep itself. The building is not specifically identified, but it's most likely a mausoleum.

> During Chapter 4 of Dragon Heist, there are three possible encounters that take place in various mausoleums depending on which season is being played.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Ah, of course. I was thinking that it must be from the farms around Waterdeep since the wall of the city was in the background, and that's why I was confused where it was from, but that's just the wall that surrounds the City of the Dead. It makes so much more sense to me now. Thank you!